# assigning attributes with new values to all objects

Tags: javascript

lets say I have created a few boxes in Raphael

```
var box1 = paper.add([
            {
                ...
            }
var box2 = paper.add([
            {
                ...
            }
var box3 = paper.add([
            {
                ...
            }
```

and I want to assign an attribute to all objects so that

```
box1.somehing=3
box2.somehing=3
box3.somehing=3
```

is there anyway to do something like

```
 *.somthing=3? to assign this value to all the objects?
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can go with :
box1.somehing = box2.somehing = box3.somehing = 3

Comment: well, I hoped there is an easier way, I want to add a new attribute to a project that has a lot of objects :\

Comment: Then maybe you should create a Container class containing all your boxes with a method to iretate through all your boxes and do a box.something = value. Maybe the method should take (something, value) in parameters